# Mapping mouse buttons with udev hwdb

Tags: udev

Following this guide: http://www.vxnick.com/blog/2014/10/binding-extra-mouse-buttons-on-linux/

I've set up a config file:

```
$ lsusb | grep G500
Bus 006 Device 007: ID 046d:c068 Logitech, Inc. G500 Laser Mouse
$ cat /etc/udev/hwdb.d/70-g500.hwdb 
keyboard:usb:v046DpC068*
  KEYBOARD_KEY_90009=9
  KEYBOARD_KEY_9000a=8
  KEYBOARD_KEY_90006=0
```

Based on the following `evtest` output:

```
Event: time 1422711060.272136, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 90009
Event: time 1422711060.272136, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 280 (?), value 1
Event: time 1422711060.272136, -------------- EV_SYN ------------
Event: time 1422711060.432134, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 90009
Event: time 1422711060.432134, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 280 (?), value 0
Event: time 1422711060.432134, -------------- EV_SYN ------------
Event: time 1422711061.461191, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 9000a
Event: time 1422711061.461191, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 281 (?), value 1
Event: time 1422711061.461191, -------------- EV_SYN ------------
Event: time 1422711061.628125, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 9000a
Event: time 1422711061.628125, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 281 (?), value 0
Event: time 1422711061.628125, -------------- EV_SYN ------------
Event: time 1422711062.725119, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 90006
Event: time 1422711062.725119, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 277 (BTN_FORWARD), value 1
Event: time 1422711062.725119, -------------- EV_SYN ------------
Event: time 1422711062.902137, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 90006
Event: time 1422711062.902137, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 277 (BTN_FORWARD), value 0
```

And yet I get no keypresses (Or change in `evtest` output) when I'm done.

(Yes I've done `udevadm` `hwdb --update`/`trigger`)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going through the same thing with a G600 and, after creating the hwdb file, I had to run (as root):

```
udevadm hwdb --update
udevadm control --reload
```

and then I had to unplug/replug the mouse. If that doesn't work, I'd suggest removing one of the space in front of each KEYBOARD_KEY lines in your configuration file. Unfortunately, I don't have a link but I did see another post while troubleshooting saying that there should be exactly one space in front of those lines. I had been using no spaces and adding only one fixed the hwdb not updating.

Comment: I was using 2 spaces in front of `KEYBOARD_KEY` but I reduced it to 1 and it's still not working. Oh dear.

Comment: Does the timestamp on /etc/udev/hwdb.bin change after you update?

Comment: @JV You should also call `udevadm trigger` after the `udevadm hwdb --update`. And any line that starts with more than one space is silently ignored for future reference.